# try to update FilterDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I try to update DataFilter for the FilterDefinition object but I got the error message

> "The DataFilter that was provided is invalid."

what is wrong with my request?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">access_token</fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:UpdateRequest>
            <ns1:Options/>
            <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:FilterDefinition">
                <ns1:ObjectID>647c8fad-bd8b-434b-b988-b93f17082c4e</ns1:ObjectID>
                <ns1:DataFilter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <ns1:Property>some custom field</ns1:Property>
                    <ns1:SimpleOperator>equals</ns1:SimpleOperator>
                    <ns1:Value>true (boolean)</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:DataFilter>   
            </ns1:Objects>
        </ns1:UpdateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer i missing this part
<ns1:DataSource xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension">
ns1:ObjectID7fc0d991-3a72-eb11-b81e-48df37861542</ns1:ObjectID>
</ns1:DataSource>